Перевод с vite на webpck. Не понимает css modules
Есть проект на Реакте, сборщик vite + ts, делаю перевод проект на вебпак. Все ок, кроме того, что возникает ошибка касаемо css модулей, будто их не видит, выдает ошибку при билде, пример:
in ./src/shared/UI/Button/Button.tsx 18:29-34
export 'default' (imported as 's') was not found in './Button.module.scss' (possible exports: btn, color_accent, color_light, container, disabled, root)

При запуске проекта, пример ошибки:
TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wrapper')

стили импортирую так: import styles from './RelatedItems.module.scss';
пробовала и так, но возникает также ошибка: import * as styles from './RelatedItems.module.scss';
Мой конфиг вебпака:
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin from '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
// import TsCheckerPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
const srcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const getSettingsForStyles = (withModules = false) => {
  return [
    isProd ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
    !withModules
      ? 'css-loader'
      : {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: {
              localIdentName: !isProd ? '[path][name]__[local]' : '[hash:base64]',
            },
          },
        },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        postcssOptions: {
          plugins: ['autoprefixer'],
        },
      },
    },
    'sass-loader',
  ];
};

export default {
  entry: path.resolve(srcPath, 'main.tsx'),
  output: {
    path: buildPath,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    libraryExport: 'default',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  target: !isProd ? 'web' : 'browserslist',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[tj]sx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        exclude: /\.module\.s?css$/,
        use: getSettingsForStyles(),
      },
      {
        test: /\.module\.s?css$/,
        use: getSettingsForStyles(true),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg)$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 10 * 1024,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
    }),
    !isProd && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),
    isProd &&
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name]-[hash].css',
      }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.jsx', '.js', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      '@pages': path.join(srcPath, 'pages'),
      '@features': path.join(srcPath, 'features'),
      '@widgets': path.join(srcPath, 'widgets'),
      '@shared': path.join(srcPath, 'shared'),
      '@entities': path.join(srcPath, 'entities'),
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 9000,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    // contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  },
};

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@widgets/*": ["widgets/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["entities/*"],
      "@features/*": ["features/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["shared/*"]
    },

    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "types": ["vite-plugin-svgr/client"],
  "include": ["src", "main.tsx", "custom.d.ts", "declaration.d.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

tsconfig.node.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["tsconfig.json"]
}

declaration.d.ts:
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: Record<string, string>;
  export default content;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

custom.d.ts:
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}

declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: Record<string, string>;
  export default content;
}

declare module '*.png' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

babel.config:
module.exports = (api) => {
  api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);

  return {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
    plugins: [process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && 'react-refresh/babel'].filter(Boolean),
  };
};

